# 5d Basis Vectors of Penrose's Tilings

Tags: projective-geometry, tiling

I have been writing some software to display/render [Penrose tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling).  I was hoping to use the [approach of projecting a 5-dimensional lattice into 2d](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-11/S0002-9947-96-01640-6/S0002-9947-96-01640-6.pdf) and apply some coloring based on regions etc.  I was successful at doing this, but I am getting shapes like the following:
[image: Penrose aspiring]

which have some of the features of a correct outcome, such as $D_5$ symmetry and bounded output values.  I am fairly certain that I need a different 5d->2d projection (right now I am mapping the 5d unit cell to a pentagon).

I was hoping to find a reference for what the basis is to get Penrose's tilings, or a principled way to calculate it myself.

Comment: What window and complementary subspace are you using for the projection?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a version of de Brujin's 'pentagrid' method. If that's the case I'd suggest reading [this classical reference](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/256644109_Algebraic_theory_of_Penrose%27s_non-periodic_tilings_of_the_plane._II).

Comment: The above plot is -10 to 10 in x/y.  I am doing a bit of reading to figure out what the complementary subspace is, give me a few minutes to figure this out.  The code is here if that helps: http://pastebin.com/Cizbfn7L.

Comment: @DanielRust Yeah.  The pentagrid method is what I am doing.  Great reference thank you!  I am a bit confused on the basis scaling still, but I think I can sort it out with these papers and the pentagrid search term.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not a programmer so I've never actually tried generating a Penrose tiling myself, although I study aperiodic tilings as my main area of research, so with that in mind, would it not be easier to generate a Penrose tiling on a computer using the substitution method (see [here](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution_rules/penrose_kite_dart) and [here](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution_rules/penrose_rhomb) )?

Comment: Unfortunately my copy of [Quasicrystals and Geometry](http://www.amazon.com/Quasicrystals-Geometry-Marjorie-Senechal/dp/0521575419) is in my office while I'm at home just now.

Comment: That book looks rad.  I know I can make the substitution version work, but part of my interest in this approach is the way in which it is parameterized allows one to change the basis vectors smoothly in space.  i.e I am eventually shooting to make a Tiling that smoothly transitions around the three famous embodiment as the patterns sweeps through $2\pi$ or something similar.

Comment: @DanielRust thanks for the leads and search terms.

Answer (score 2):

This [reference](http://cs.williams.edu/~bailey/06le.pdf) clarified everything for me.  The grid $j$'th gridline is given by
$$\vec{x} \cdot \vec{\epsilon}_j + \gamma_j = N,$$

for some integer $N$.

Where the grid directions are given by:
$$\epsilon_j = \left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{5}\right), \ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{5}\right)  \right) ,$$
for j = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and the shift of the each of the gradation from the origin must obey:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^4 \gamma_j = 0$$

Thanks all.