# Projection method: What's the 5D rotation matrix to get Penrose lattice

Tags: projection-matrices

I want to project a 5D periodic grid to 2D Penrose lattice. Although I have a code that seems to do it (image below), with matrix elements related to Golden ratio, I wonder where I can find a reference for it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do we agree that it is the Penrose tiling given in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) ?

Comment: Why don't you want to answer ? This site is for making people interact. Besides, I have googled and **easily** found references with keywords "Penrose tiling 5D" 1) on this site 2 references: (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/868115) and (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/791848) 2) a journal paper (https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0503/0503464.pdf) and many others...

Comment: Thanks. The pictures on Wikipedia looks similar, but there are a few different Penrose tilings.

Comment: This is why I asked you my question. Besides, if you are interesting by these questions, I advise you to look at "Tilings and Patterns" (B. Grünbaum and G.C. Shephard) Dover 2016.